# Program dismisses steps when running quickly (Java)

Tags: java, jar, sleep

I am running a tool that runs an external Java program several times in its operation. The external tool starts with opening a JOptionPane inside a JFrame.

Here is a test script I wrote to try to solve my issue.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
            //Thread.sleep(1000);

            String toRun = "java -jar \"" + "C:\\Folder\\File.jar" + "\" " + i;

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(toRun, null, new File("C:\\Folder"));
        }
    }
}
```

When this runs, only the final run's JOptionPane (i=5) appears, but it seems that others are "trying" to appear as panes seem to be opening and immediately closing.

When I uncomment the Thread.sleep however, all of the panes open separately. If i set the sleep to 300 (0.3 seconds) about half of the panes appear, usually the first and last ones.

I would like to find a way to run all instances of the external program fully without needing to use Thread.sleep() at all, if possible.

Edit: As per requirement's I've minimalised my external program as well.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class File {
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    private static String doc1Address = "C:\\Folder\\doc1.csv";
    private static String doc2Address = "C:\\Folder\\doc2.csv";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if(args.length == 1) {

            SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String currentDate = form.format(date);

            //Save Backup of doc1
            String doc1BackAddress = doc1Log.substring(0, doc1Log.length()-15) + "doc1Back " + currentDate + ".csv";
            Path todoc1 = Paths.get(doc1Address);
            Path todoc1Back = Paths.get(doc1BackAddress);
            Files.copy(todoc1, todoc1Back);
            Files.setAttribute(todoc1Back, "dos:readonly", true);

            //Save Backup of doc2
            String doc2BackAddress = doc2Log.substring(0, doc2Log.length()-16) + "doc2Back " + currentDate + ".csv";
            Path todoc2 = Paths.get(doc2Address);
            Path todoc2Back = Paths.get(doc2BackAddress);
            Files.copy(todoc2, todoc2Back);
            Files.setAttribute(todoc2Back, "dos:readonly", true);

            //Format JFrame
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLodoc1ionRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, args[0]);
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are they supposed to run in parallel or one after the other?

Comment: In parallel. When the sleep function is included, all 6 panes appear one after the other in quick succession, so that all 6 are on the screen at once, and the following functions of that program run in parallel.

Comment: What's wrong with running them one after the other?

Comment: Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();  rt.exec("notepad");

      rt.exec("cmd");

 etc

Comment: I don't really see how that would be any different, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Post an [mcve] that reproduces your problem. You say there is some issues with popping up option panes but I don't see any code that opens option panes

Comment: It totally depends on how the File.jar creates these JPanels. Unless you don't provide us code from it it would be only suggestions and workarounds but not a solutions

Answer (score 0):

Found my own issue; since the backup files use the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss`, and files saved during the same second result in a `FileAlreadyExists` Exception, meaning only the first file to finish saving allows the program to continue running.

Having a 1 second pause results in the files having different save names, so no error occurs.

Having a sub-1 second pause results in some file name overlap, but some different names too, hence some files appear.

Solution: either change the name format (i.e. include milliseconds), or include the backup functions in an if-statement, that is ignored if the file with the same time already exists.

(also; thank you @ErwinBolwidt, in being encouraged to format my question properly I realised that the issue in my code was not where I assumed it to be).